# How to deal with NaN?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function sumOfColumns(tableID, columnIndex) {
    var tot = 0;
    $("#" + tableID + " tr").children("td:nth-child(" + columnIndex + ")").each(function () {
        tot += parseFloat($(this).html());
    });
    return tot;
}
var _totalhours = sumOfColumns("tblEmpEarnings", 3);
```

When I debug `_totalhours` is giving me `NaN`. Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: Could you show me HTML?

Comment: Debug: `console.log($(this).html(), parseFloat($(this).html()));`

Answer (score 7):

`NaN` means "Not a Number" and is a [keyword in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN), not just jQuery.  It is most likely the result of you trying to use `parseFloat` on letters instead of numbers.

How do you deal with it?

> Equality operator (== and ===) cannot be used to test a value against
>   NaN. Use [Number.isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) or [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should test the value before trying to parse it to make sure it is a number.  You can use the isNaN() javascript function, NaN means Not a Number.

```
var tot = 0,
    value = $(this).html();

if(!isNan(value))
{
    tot += parseFloat(value);
}
```

Since parse float returns NaN and in javaScript NaN evaluates to false, you could also do the following:

```
var tot = 0,
    value = parseFloat($(this).html());

if(value)
{
    tot += value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `0` as a fallback value (in case the number is `0` or `NaN`):

```
tot += +$(this).html() || 0;
```

This way, if one value isn't numeric, you will be able to sum the other ones.